# Unable to run Anime JS

Tags: javascript, html, anime.js

I know that this issue has already been posted but I found nothing that could help me with my problem. So here it is: I would like to create some animated stuff on my website using AnimeJS, but I'm unable to run the simplest animation, even those from the anime.js documentation and examples.

I found someone who had the same issue and solved it by **running the code after the document is loaded, but in my case looks like it is not the solution**n. I installed anime.js using npm, and I am using nothing more than this and Jquery on my page. Here is the code with the example of the documentation:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cssSelector = anime({
    targets: '#cssSelector .el',
    translateX: 250
  });
});
```

```css
#cssSelector {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100Px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cssSelector">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="square el"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because the element `#cssSelector .el` has zero height and is not the black rectangle you see on the screen. Change your selector instead to the element that actually has the black background, i.e. `#cssSelector` and you will see it work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cssSelector = anime({
    targets: '#cssSelector',
    translateX: 250
  });
});
```

```css
#cssSelector {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cssSelector">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="square el"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively change your stylesheet so the styles are applied to the `.el` element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cssSelector = anime({
    targets: '#cssSelector .el',
    translateX: 250
  });
});
```

```css
#cssSelector .el {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cssSelector">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="square el"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```